# How do I make the White outline border

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

How do I make the outline as pictured?

Comment: Hi Rhi, welcome to GD.SE! It would be helpful to have some more information about how you are trying to accomplish the stroke in your question along with what you have tried already. This will help the community narrow down a more accurate answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is called a [Sticker outline](http://www.photoshoplab.com/peeled-sticker-style-effect.html). Found by googling.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're in Photoshop:

- have your shape as a layer without any background
- select your shape by Magic Wand (tolerace=255)
- expand the selection to the wanted size (Select > Modify > Expand)
- create two more layers - White and Grey - below the shape
- floodfill the selections in layers: White by white, Grey by BLACK
- remove the selection (you can get it back using the shape)
- Gaussian Blur the Grey layer(black spreads as grey)

It's well possible that you must a little bit smoothen the edge in the White layer to remove the jaggies and to make it overall less offensive. Then, select the white shape, invert the selection, feather it and press DEL.

See a screenshot; this is a MS Word clipart cow

[image]

Assuming you're in Ai or otherwise work in vector domain

- make a copy of your shape
- if it's a group, then Ungroup all
- merge all subshapes together as an union
- stretch the result to wanted size
- select white fill and grey outline; alternatively select no outline and insert effect Outer Glow, set glow color=grey
- put it under your shape

Assuming you're composing in a DTP application: Explore the available object effects. It's well possible to find a suitable glow or shadow or a combination of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could also go the way telegram stickers are usually made. Telegram even offers a [Sample Photoshop File](https://telegram.org/img/StickerExample.psd).

Basically, you create a layer with just your shape. Then you doubleclick the layer to get to the layer style menu. There, you can set effects like "Glow outwards" or what it's called in english.
[image: Ebenenstil]

This way, you can easily change the size of the border later. Just play around with the settings until it looks like you want.